# Android Finish() ignores addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-finish

```
Intent set_login_screen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyClass.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(set_login_screen);
finish();
```

As the title states the `Finish()` command makes the no Animation flag to be ignored. If i out comment `Finish()` then the no animation transition happens else the standard animation transition will happen.

Why is that and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding `<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>` to a style which i use as a theme for the activity in the manifest.

example

```
 <style name="NoTitleBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".myActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NoTitleBar"></activity>
```